# Ubuntu 18.04 - Launching Chrome shows under the VSCode icon instead

Tags: google-chrome, icons, 18.04, dock

Whenever I click the Chrome icon, Ubuntu 18.04 adds the VSCode icon to the dock or adds another dot to the VSCode icon instead of the Chrome icon. The Chrome icon doesn't display any dots, it only acts as a launcher.

If I click the VSCode icon it shows the Chrome windows, but I can also right-click the icon and select New Window to launch a VSCode window. A new VSCode window also adds another dot to the VSCode icon.

How do I get the Chrome icon working again so that Chrome dots are not added to VSCode?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this issue with Chrome showing under Slack's icon as well.  Maybe it has something to do with electron based apps.

Answer (score 4):

You might have installed `VSCode` as a `snap` package, which causes `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` to be set to `~/snap/code/common/.cache`, which could cause some cli tools to mistake that for your cache directory, and install/launch binaries from there.

If you install VSCode from the `.deb` download, it should fix your issue

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be fixed with the following command.

**Please note that this will reset all custom settings on the dock, such as custom favorites and panel extensions, which is undesirable.**

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

After running this command you may need to reboot.

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: didn't work for me either

Comment: This did all the undesirable things mentioned and didn't fix the issue.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually this did work after a reboot. I can't edit my comment and I can't upvote the answer unless it's edited. @Allan Bogh could you edit and add the reboot step then I can upvote? Thanks.

Comment: +1 It worked after reboot. But maybe put your warning about the reset in bold. Because this indeed resets the dock completely. Which is a side effect that I suspect will make a lot of people mad.

Comment: Side effects I noticed: 1. favorites (dock) are gone. 2. custom keyboard shortcuts are gone. 3. gnome extensions are all disabled.

Comment: That reset a lot more settings than just those relating to the dock.

Comment: didn't work for me. + keyboard shortcuts and terminal profile are gone(

Comment: your solution destroyed my settings

Comment: It might be enough to reset `/org/gnome/shell`.

Comment: It did work for me. I did it with the chrome tab opened from vscode. then I just pressed `reboot`, and wait for it to reload.